# Error messges: "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type"

Tags: swiftui

I am working on just making a simple trivia app where you will eventually pick one of two answers for a question. So far I have some variables and arrays to keep my information on what is correct and what is false. I have some errors I can't identify any help? I am using SwiftUI but I am really new.

The problem is that my VStack is giving me this messge "Result of 'VStack' initilizer is unused"

And my View is giving me this error: "Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type"

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var currentNum = 0
    var person = ["Michael Jackson","Elton John","Prince"]
    var dead = [1,0,1]
    // 1 = yes 0 = no
    @State var correct = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text(person[currentNum])
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Dead")
            })
            
            
            
        }
        
        func checkDead() {
            if dead[currentNum] == 1{
                return correct = true
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Thanks - NM

Answer (score 0):

The return keyword is necessary, along with moving the nested function earlier.

```swift
var body: some View {
  func checkDead() {
    if dead[currentNum] == 1 {
      return correct = true
    }
  }

  return VStack {
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move function `checkDead` out of `body`

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(person[currentNum])
        Button(action: {
            
        }, label: {
            Text("Dead")
        })
    }
}

func checkDead() {
    if dead[currentNum] == 1{
        return correct = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text(person[currentNum])
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Dead")
            })
            
            
            
        }
        
// Problem Starts! :
        func checkDead() {
            if dead[currentNum] == 1{
                return correct = true
            }
        }
// Problem Ends!
        
    }
```

you are declaring a function inside a variable (declaring function `checkDead` inside variable `body`)

long story short, dont do that! declare your functions in scope of your class, not in the body:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var currentNum = 0
    var person = ["Michael Jackson","Elton John","Prince"]
    var dead = [1,0,1]
    // 1 = yes 0 = no
    @State var correct = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text(person[currentNum])
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Dead")
            })
            
            
            
        }
        
        // func checkDead() {
        //    if dead[currentNum] == 1{
        //        return correct = true
        //    }
        //}
        // move it to the struct's scope and outside the variable `body`
    }

//here is where it should be
 func checkDead() {
            if dead[currentNum] == 1{
                correct = true
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: you are also trying to return something in your function. i don't know what do you want to do but it hink that just extra and you should delete it